# Express Server Handler "app" not defined in my handler.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

question#2 from me so far...I'm trying to host my own express server on localhost:3000 in my server.js file. The problem I run into is in my handler file, on the line app.post, app is undefined...How do I let this file know the scope of app from my server.js file?

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const ADD_MERCHANT = `
mutation ($name: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
  insert_merchants_one(object: {
    name: $name,
    email: $email,
    password: $password
  }) {
    id
    name
    created_at
  }
}
`;

// execute the parent operation in Hasura
const execute = async (variables) => {
  const fetchResponse = await fetch(
    "***********************v1/graphql",
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query: ADD_MERCHANT,
        variables
      })
    }
  );
  const data = await fetchResponse.json();
  console.log('DEBUG: ', data);
  return data;
};
  

// Request Handler
app.post('/signupMerchant', async (req, res) => {

  // get request input
  const { name, email, password } = req.body.input;

  // run some business logic
  let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
  // execute the Hasura operation
  const { data, errors } = await execute({ name, email, password: hashedPassword });

...

module.exports;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `const app = express()` in your server.js, add `module.exports.app = app` to server.js, then add `const { app } = require('./server')` in your handlers file. This means you should not call `app.listen` directly in `server.js` though, you'll want to have a third file (index.js would be a good one) that also requires `app` and then calls `app.listen`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I needed to modify some of the codegen from Graphql, but this got me started down the right road.